# Disqus comments shown in all Blog posts in Django 1.5

Tags: django, disqus

Before someone telling me that this question is duplicate, I have read the solutions for all django-disqus related questions similar to my problem.

1. I have a Django based blog application.
2. Downloaded and installed django-disqus (pip install django-disqus)
3. Followed the instructions from this documentation (http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html)
4. But comments are shown in all the blog posts.

I have a base.html file which includes header and footer and is generic throughout the site. I have post.html where specific post will be displayed when clicked from base.html.

So I have loaded `{% load disqus_tags %}` at the top of post.html and included the javascript like this

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'impras';
    var disqus_url = 'http://impras.in/{{ post.get_absolute_url }}';
    var disqus_identifier = '{{ post.get_absolute_url }}';
    var disqus_title = '{{ post.title }}';
    var disqus_developer = 1;

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })(); 
    </script>
```

I am testing this in local machine and not in production server, so i have set `DEBUG=True` and so `disqus_developer = 1`.

Comment: sorry, what is your question? how to disable disqus on specific blog posts? how about a 'has_comments' boolean and an if statement?

Comment: No not about disabling disqus on specific blog posts. The thing is when I open a specific post and comment on that post, it should be displayed on that specific post alone, but what happens is when I open any post, the same comment is available there.

Comment: ah ok, how does your `post.get_absolute_url` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any javascript in django view. 
I solve **same problem** by just removing `{% disqus_dev %}` from my template.